# How Stream methods in java-8 are implemented?

Tags: java, java-8, polymorphism, java-stream

While I was experimenting with the new java-8 Stream I wanted to take a peek under the hood and see how its methods are implemented so I take a look at the implementation of Stream class and found all the methods are abstract.

my question is how the methods like `distinct()` and `map()` works it must have concrete implementation somewhere, where these methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out the class that I was looking for is [**`ReferencePipeline`**](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java) which as [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) said is extended from [`AbstractPipeline`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b68/docs/api/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.html), 
and it's better to look at it before `ReferencePipeline`.

and we get an object from this class when we create Stream by `Arrays.stream()` or calling `stream()` on `List` object or any other way.

so it's just basic polymorphism.

Comment: haha, that what I was thinking at first when I didn't see any implemented I think it might be native methods or something new in java-8 or some kind of black magic but it turns out it's just regular polymorphism.

Comment: The core implementation is AbstractPipeline, which is extended by ReferencePipeline, IntPipeline, etc, which in turn implement Stream<T>, IntStream, etc.  No magic.